# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using third party library in Android application (Aviary SDK)

Tags: android

This has been driving me absolutely crazy. There's 101 answers to this kind of problem scattered across Stack Overflow but nothing seems to work for me.

Here's the story:

1. I downloaded the Aviary SDK (if that's relevant) and imported their library project into my workspace
2. I added their Library under Project -> Android -> Add.. and it's checked off there
3. The JAR (aviary-sdk.jar) containing the class that apparently is missing at runtime (com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity) is listened under Android Dependencies in Project -> Java Build Path
4. The project builds correctly, but at runtime it throws a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when trying to launch this activity

I've tried a bunch of things (checking and unchecking things in Order and Export, reordering things there, etc.) but nothing is taking. I also tried just manually including the JAR in the /libs folder, but this SDK depends on a bunch of other things in that library project (e.g. themes) and having the SDK referenced twice doesn't work either.

I'm completely stumped here. I've looked at all kinds of other answers and nothing seems to work. I'm starting to get the feeling that this method of referencing other libraries is no longer supported...?

**Edit**: I've created a fresh Android project and reproduced the problem there, too. I suspect it has to be something stupid in my build environment:
[image: aviary test app]
[image: aviary test app project properties]
[image: aviary test app build path]

Comment: Does the Aviary SDK have any dependencies of its own? Are you including the android-support library?

Comment: Yes, I've included the Android support-v4 JAR as well. The missing class is one I can *see* when I expand the aviary-sdk.jar in my project's Android Dependencies, which is part of why it's so frustrating...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

After trying everything in the settings, I decided it was the IDEs fault. I deleted my ADT and started a new one, new workspace, imported all my projects (as-is), and launched from there. Everything works.

I guess this is my punishment for always complaining about how Vim was better than any IDE... Ya got me, Eclipse.

*disgruntled sigh*

Comment: i am having the same problem. It works fine on Android studio simulator but on genymotion and on my s5 it gives same classDefFoundError. :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried importing the aviary-sdk.jar as an external jar?

1. Copy the aviary-sdk.jar into the libs folder on your project
2. Right click on your project, Build Path -> Add External Libraries
3. Add the aviary-sdk.jar from your libs folder inside your project

Hope this helps, Good luck ^^

Comment: The problem with that is it conflicts with the SDK that is automatically included as an Android Dependency when you reference the library project. The build process complains about having that JAR in there twice.

Comment: Does the SDK Library imported as Project on Eclipse or not?

Comment: [2013-05-28 12:55:35 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/aviary/android/feather/Constants;
[2013-05-28 12:55:36 - Bridgit] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/aviary/android/feather/Constants;

Comment: The SDK library is referenced from Properties -> Android.

Comment: Have you edit your AndroidManifest XML as shown in the documentation? about adding reference to FeatherActivity

Comment: Yeah, definitely. It doesn't seem to matter. In my minimal test application, I didn't even try to launch the activity, just reference the class (via FeatherActivity.class.getName()), same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try a few things,

Number 1: Regarding conflicting jars, it's probably refering to the support library. So go ahead and right click on your library project, and select the option 'Add Support Library'. This downloads the most recent support library, then do the same for your own application project.

The problem is that the library may be using a different support.jar than yours.

Number 2: If that doesn't fix the issue, go to your project properties, Java Build Path, and select 'Order and Export', and make sure that both 'Android Private Libraries' and 'Android Dependencies' are checked.

Clean the project, and try running again.

Comment: The conflicting JARs comes from when I manually included aviary-sdk.jar instead of including it as a dependency. I don't get that error otherwise.